# PFQueryTableViewController should not load any objects until user interaction happens?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I am using a PFQueryTableViewController that should only load objects after a user has pressed a button. The problem is lying in the method `- (PFQuery *)queryForTable`.

Here is my code:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    if (self.searchText) {
        PFQuery *titleQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"photo"];
        [titleQuery whereKey:@"titleKey" containsString:self.searchText];

        PFQuery *descriptionQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"photo"];
        [descriptionQuery whereKey:@"descriptionKey" containsString:self.searchText];

        PFQuery *searchQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[titleQuery, descriptionQuery]];

        return stringSearchQuery;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

The problem is that I manually call `- (void)loadObjects` at some other point when a user decides to. By returning nil in this method the PFQueryTableView just leaves the loading indicator on indefinitely and user interaction is disabled.

What do I need to return in order for the table view to just be blank and then after the user interaction will load?

Comment: you could check the return value at a point and stop indicator as per required. Also more code will let me know where you starting n stopping indicator.

Comment: What is your use case? Is it that the "button" is a "search" button? So you only want to show search results, and nothing before the user performs a search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking whether searchText exists, try defaulting it to something that will never occur in the database, i.e. a dummy string like "@@@@@@@ Dummy string. Will never occur in database @@@@@@@".

This way, the query will be performed but not return any results - which should leave the tableview empty. Then, when the user enters a search string and taps the button, the queryForTable code is executed with real search string.

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing I in my if statement I left it as is, but then below I created a basic query that would never return anything. This resulted in items being found only if searchText is not nil, which means the user searched something and pressed the search button.

Comment: Great. You should accept the answer then to close the question